# Выставка в базу данных в массив

Tags: php, mysql, массивы, insert

```
if(isset($_POST['idpupil']))    {$idpupil = $_POST['idpupil'];}
if(isset($_POST['date']))       {$date = $_POST['date'];}
if(isset($_POST['idteacher']))  {$idteacher = $_POST['idteacher'];}
$come = 1;

$insert = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO yoqlama(idpupil,date,come,idteacher) VALUES ('$idpupil','$date','$come','$idteacher')");
```

В этом случае нужно добавит 5 строк в базу с 5 разных ID учеником, но у меня получило только последние один результат

Comment: С чего вдруг будет создано 5 записей, если запрос всего 1?

Answer (score 0):

**1 запрос = 1 результат.**
В вашем случае вы пишите только одну строку в Базу. Чтобы дописать оставшиеся нужно иметь столько же запросов, сколько вам нужно написать в Базу.